# × React: TypeError: Object(...) is not a function Stripe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm working on creating a ecommerce website.

It's my first time working with Stripe and I have no idea why I'm getting this error.

This is my code pre stripe

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./Header";
import Home from "./Home";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Checkout from "./Checkout";
import Login from "./Login";
import Payment from "./Payment";
import { auth } from "./firebase";
import { useStateValue } from "./StateProvider";


function App() {
  const [{}, dispatch] = useStateValue();

  useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {
      console.log("THE USER OS >>>", authUser);

      if (authUser) {
        dispatch({
          type: "SET_USER",
          user: authUser,
        });
      } else {
        dispatch({
          type: "SET_USER",
          user: null,
        });
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    // BEM
    <Router>
      <div className="app">
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login">
            <Login />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/checkout">
            <Header />
            <Checkout />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/payment">
            <Header />
            <Payment />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Header />
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my code post stripe attempt

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./Header";
import Home from "./Home";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Checkout from "./Checkout";
import Login from "./Login";
import Payment from "./Payment";
import { auth } from "./firebase";
import { useStateValue } from "./StateProvider";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";

const promise = loadStripe(
  "pk_live_51JSoCCJMzgZXrTSfThco77AU3gAgoJSXJdClY0msBR7Z3r3E7v38j1O17u0cDC9vwAbfdvS522hISYXEQ5n7ccn400AT2T3NaN"
);

function App() {
  const [{}, dispatch] = useStateValue();

  useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {
      console.log("THE USER OS >>>", authUser);

      if (authUser) {
        dispatch({
          type: "SET_USER",
          user: authUser,
        });
      } else {
        dispatch({
          type: "SET_USER",
          user: null,
        });
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    // BEM
    <Router>
      <div className="app">
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login">
            <Login />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/checkout">
            <Header />
            <Checkout />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/payment">
            <Header />
            <Elements stripe={promise}>
              <Payment />
            </Elements>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Header />
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'm following a tutorial online and when they add

```
const promise = loadStripe(
  "pk_live_51JSoCCJMzgZXrTSfThco77AU3gAgoJSXJdClY0msBR7Z3r3E7v38j1O17u0cDC9vwAbfdvS522hISYXEQ5n7ccn400AT2T3NaN"
);
```

There are no problems however whenever I add that to my code I get a TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

I've tried to research problems with my code but wasn't able to find any solutions.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import `loadStripe` from normal stripe js instead of the react version like so:

```js
import {loadStripe} from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import {Elements} from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
```